# Joomla upgradation error

Tags: joomla, joomla1.6

I have site in joomla 1.6 on server and when i tried to update joomla it showes me this error: `"-1 - An error has occurred Copy failed"` Whats wrong? please help me

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to update it directly on the server?

Comment: yes i am updating on server side

Comment: @Manan: Check folder permission.

Comment: Was this a 1.6.0 site? You might just want to manually overwrite the files. The autoupdate was a little flakey early on and it definitely could not do the database changes.

Comment: @Elin: yes I have in 1.6. how to overwrite manually and which files?

Comment: Just get the zip from the download site and overwrite them all. The problem will be that some files should be removed and also you will need to do some database updates but you should be able to do that, though you might have to discover install various things to get to that point.  I believe that docs.joomla.org has instructions for updating from 1.6 to the current release in that series which is 2.5.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just download the upgrade package from joomla.org and overwrite the files on your host with ftp.
Once uploaded, go in administrator/extensions/manage extensions/database and press the "fix" button.
Clean the cache and tmp folders and you're ready to go.